# Как в css сделать разрыв в border?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы сверху и снизу пустое , а в середине стояла линия?

Comment: Никак, в табличной верстке внутри каждой ячейки поместите блок `div` и его стилизуйте, внешний отступ задаётся через __padding__

Answer (score 4):

Может кому-то понадобится :

```
border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom, 
      #0d0d12,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 
      #0d0d12
    ) 1 30% 1;
```